# How to parse 3.5GB XML file based on attributes of a tag?

Tags: python, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I want to parse this XML in python. I want to find only the attributes of a particular tag.

`<managedObject class="XXX" version="XXX18" distName="XXX-RC8/XXX-212404" id="142022">`

If I have a tag like above. I have to find all entries based on either version, class, distname or id only.

Currently I am using:

```
etree.XPath("child::Title[contains(text(), 'managedObject')]")`
```

This does not work for the current file as the tag has many attributes. The file contents looks like below. I would need an optimized solution to read a 3GB file not taking too much of RAM.

```
<managedObject class="XXX" version="XXX18" distName="XXX-RC8/XXX-212404" id="142022">
      <list name="Options">
        <p>0</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>6</p>
        <p>7</p>
        <p>8</p>
        <p>9</p>
        <p>10</p>
        <p>11</p>
        <p>12</p>
        <p>13</p>
        <p>14</p>
        <p>15</p>
        <p>18</p>
        </list>
      <p name="SomeOption1">12</p>
      <p name="SomeOption2">4</p>
      <p name="SomeOption3">2</p>
      <p name="SomeOption4">0</p>
      <p name="SomeOption1">12</p>
      <p name="SomeOption2">4</p>
      <p name="SomeOption3">2</p>
      <p name="SomeOption4">0</p>
      <p name="OtherOption">12</p>
      <p name="XOtherOption2">4</p>
      <p name="XOtherOption3">2</p>
      <p name="XOtherOption4">0</p>
      <p name="XXXOtherOption1">12</p>
      <p name="XXXOtherOption2">4</p>
      <p name="XXXOtherOption3">2</p>
      <p name="XXXOtherOption4">0</p>
      <p name="YYYYXXXOtherOption1">12</p>
      <p name="YYYYXXXOtherOption2">4</p>
      <p name="YYYYXXXOtherOption3">2</p>
      <p name="YYYYXXXOtherOption4">0</p>
</managedObject>
```

Comment: You could use the sax or expat parser. Both call handler functions (defined by you) when e. g. a start tag is parsed (or other things are recognized). Then you only have to check if it is the desired tag, process the attributes and parsing continues. These parsers don't store large parts of the document in memory.

Comment: What are you expecting for output?

Comment: Except <list name> tag, I want all information inside <managedObject> tag in an output file(csv or txt>